# HTML/Javascript Find in Tables but not including non searchable areas

Tags: javascript, html, search, find

Wants to integrate a filter function.
I want to search in the TBODY-Tag.
My Javascript works fine for all Content in the TBODY-Tag.
But there are areas that should not be searched.
An idea how to realize this?

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myInput").keyup(function(){
        filter = new RegExp($(this).val(),'i');
        $("#myTable tbody").filter(function(){
            $(this).each(function(){
                found = false;
                $(this).children().each(function(){
                    content = $(this).html();
                    if(content.match(filter))
                    {
                        found = true;
                    }
                });
                if(!found)
                {
                    $(this).hide();
                }
                else
                {
                    $(this).show();
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
 <input id="myInput" type="text" name="search" />
    <table id="myTable">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    That's great searchable content.
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    That's great searchable content.
                    <div>That's also great content, but non searchable</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
           ...
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Please provide us with a complete example of your snippet. It seems to be lacking an input (as you are trying to attach an event handler to an input of id: `#myInput`). Seems more like a regex question as well. You are trying to hide the input or table elements when the value of the input matches the regex?

Comment: `$("#myTable tbody").filter(...)` is the part of the code which you tell your javascript to filter out. You might want to change that part to meet your specifics. (e.g.: `$("#myTable tbody > #myspecific-element").filter(...)` )

Comment: But I want to find matches in the whole TBody excluding specialy areas, to hide / show the complete TBODY

Comment: Following solution:

Comment: FYI, you can just use `$(this).toggle(found)` instead of an if/else statement with show()/hide() - That takes 8 lines of your code down to 1 - http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution:

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#inputSearch").keyup(function(){
        filter = new RegExp($(this).val(),'i');
        $("#tableServiceplan tbody").each(function(){
                found = false;
                $(this).find(".searchable").each(function(){
                    content = $(this).html();
                    if(content.match(filter)){
                        console.log($(this).html);
                        found = true;
                    }
                });
                if(!found){
                    $(this).hide();
                }
                else{
                    $(this).show();
                }
        });
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<input id="myInput" type="text" name="search" />
<table id="myTable">
<tbody>
  <tr>
      <td>
          <div class="searchable">That's great searchable content.</div>
     </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>
          <div class="searchable">That's great searchable content.</div>
          <div>That's also great content, but non searchable</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody>
  ...
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following solution works for me:

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#inputSearch").keyup(function(){
        filter = new RegExp($(this).val(),'i');
        $("#tableServiceplan tbody").filter(function(){
            $(this).each(function(){
                found = false;
                $(this).find("#searchable").each(function(){
                    content = $(this).html();
                    if(content.match(filter)){
                        found = true;
                    }
                });
                if(!found){
                    $(this).hide();
                }
                else{
                    $(this).show();
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<input id="myInput" type="text" name="search" />
<table id="myTable">
<tbody>
  <tr>
      <td>
          <div id="searchable">That's great searchable content.</div>
     </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>
          <div id="searchable">That's great searchable content.</div>
          <div>That's also great content, but non searchable</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody>
  ...
</tbody>
</table>
```